# Image in jPlayer playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am working on jplayer but I want to add the image in the playlist, that is inside the poster URL.
So, basically I want the image to be clicked to show or play the song instead of only text.

[image]

Following is my code that I copied from jplayer demo. But I don't find any solution which can add image to the playlist against each song.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/add-on/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
        {
            title:"Cro Magnon Man",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg",
            poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png"
        }
    ], {

        play:function(a){
            console.log(a.jPlayer.status.media.poster);   
        },
        swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "oga, mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio" role="application" aria-label="media player">
    <div class="jp-type-playlist">
        <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
            <div class="jp-controls">
                <button class="jp-previous" role="button" tabindex="0">previous</button>
                <button class="jp-play" role="button" tabindex="0">play</button>
                <button class="jp-next" role="button" tabindex="0">next</button>
                <button class="jp-stop" role="button" tabindex="0">stop</button>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-progress">
                <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                    <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-volume-controls">
                <button class="jp-mute" role="button" tabindex="0">mute</button>
                <button class="jp-volume-max" role="button" tabindex="0">max volume</button>
                <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-time-holder">
                <div class="jp-current-time" role="timer" aria-label="time">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="jp-duration" role="timer" aria-label="duration">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-toggles">
                <button class="jp-repeat" role="button" tabindex="0">repeat</button>
                <button class="jp-shuffle" role="button" tabindex="0">shuffle</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-playlist">
            <ul>
                <li>&nbsp;</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the title in the script to below. Avoid line break when adding the inline code, this will break the js

```
 title:"<div> <button onclick='location.href=\"https://miltonkeyneswebsitedesign.com\";' style='padding: 0px; margin: 0px'> <img align='top' src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'></button > Cro Magnon Man </div> ",
```